# Azure Storage Blob container - restrict IP addressese for anonymous videos

Tags: ip-address, azure-blob-storage

I would like to restrict videos to be accessible by only certain IP addressese inside a container. Is there a way to configure a container such taht all videos inside that container are accessible from only inside my network. Keep in mind all videos are still going to be anonymous.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily restrict access to IP address or create a virtual network in Storage account level. According to the documentation,

> *A shared access signature (SAS) is a URI that grants restricted access rights to Azure Storage resources. You can provide a shared access signature to clients who should not be trusted with your storage account key but whom you wish to delegate access to certain storage account resources. By distributing a shared access signature URI to these clients, you grant them access to a resource for a specified period of time.*

Click `Shared access signature` in your storage account containing the container containing videos, and restrict IPs, start and end time as well :)

[image]